# Controller for handling user registration

Tags: php, beginner, object-oriented, mvc, laravel

I spent a lot of time doing [Go Horse Extreme programming](http://www.carlostristacci.com.br/blog/extreme-go-horse-xgh/), but now I want to be a better person.

How can I make this method smaller, better, more OOP?

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function store()
{
    if (!User::is_valid(Input::all()))
    {
        Flash::error(User::$errors->first());

        return Redirect::back()->withInput();
    }

    $existing_user = User::where('email', Input::get('email'))->first();

    if (is_null($existing_user)) // The user does not exists.
    {
        // Prepare user data
        $user_input = Input::only(
            'firstName',
            'lastName',
            'email',
            'password');

        $confirmation_token = str_random(60);
        $user_data = array_merge($user_input, ['confirmation_token' => $confirmation_token]);

        // Store user
        $new_user = User::create($user_data);

        // Prepare email
        $data['name'] = Input::get('firstName') . ' ' . Input::get('lastName');
        $data['confirmation_token'] = $confirmation_token;
        $mail_subject = 'Confirmação de e-mail';

        // Send email
        Mail::send('emails.auth.email_confirmation', $data, function ($message) use ($mail_subject)
        {
            $message->to(Input::get('email'))->subject($mail_subject);
        });

        // Log the new user in
        Auth::login($new_user);

        $flash_message = sprintf(
            'Enviamos um email para <strong>%s</strong>. Confirme sua identidade',
            Input::get('email')
        );

        Flash::warning($flash_message);

        return Redirect::route('admin.dashboard');
    } else
    {
        if ($existing_user->is_active())
        {
            //Try to validate
            $stored = $existing_user->password;
            $typed = Input::get('password');
            $match = Hash::check($typed, $stored);

            if (!$match)
            {
                Flash::warning(
                    'Você já possui uma conta.
                    Faça login para continuar.'
                );

                return Redirect::route('login');
            } else
            {
                Auth::login($existing_user);
                Flash::message(
                    'Você já possui uma conta.
                    Bem vindo de volta!'
                );

                return Redirect::route('admin.dashboard');
            }
        } else
        {
            Auth::login($existing_user);

            $flash_message = sprintf(
                'Enviamos um email para <strong>%s</strong>. Confirme sua identidade [Reenviar]',
                $existing_user->email
            );

            Flash::warning($flash_message);

            return Redirect::route('admin.dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```

It just handles user registration. Everything seems to be working when I run my Behat tests, but I feel (deep in my soul) that things could be a lot better.

Comment: You could watch these videos, they will help you **https://laracasts.com/search?q=refactoring**

Comment: I am a laracasts subscriber... But never seen any of these. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you can refactor this method but since you are using Laravel things are pretty easy. Here is my attempt on refactoring (I'd rather call it re-writing) this method.

First of all, this controller is overloaded with so many responsibilities, a controllers sole job should only be to accept an `HTTP Request`, defer the execution to responsible object and deliver an `HTTP Response`, that is all a controller need to do. so lets refactor it first.

#### Defer execution to service class

I'd create a service class with name `AccountService` and inject it into `AccountController` (or whatever you call it in your case), then on `AccountService` I'd create a method named

```
createNewAcocunt($firstName, $lastName, $email, $password)
```

which will validate the data and create new account.

#### Take care of responsibilities

The `else` part of controller method `store()` defeats the purpose of REST thingy, I'd just issue a redirect to login page with an appropriate message instead of trying to log them in. all of login stuff and account activation status checking should be performed over login route so it clearly does not belongs to the account creator (or signup) route. with these 2 things in place the controller method `store()` would look like this

```
public function store()
{
    $details = Input::only('firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'password');
    try {
        $user = $this->accountService->createNewAccount($details['firstName'], $details['lastName'], $details['email'], $details['password']);
        Auth::login($user->id);
        return Redirect::route('admin.dashboard');
    } catch (ValidationException $validationEx) {
        return Redirect::back()->withError($validationEx->getErrors()); // assuming you set errors on exception object before throwing it
    }
}
```

Now over to the `AccountService` class.
The method `createNewAcocunt($firstName, $lastName, $email, $password)`, by its name, should create an account with data fed to it. In case there is an error it should throw an exception.

#### Take advantage of events as they happen

Now, you need to take care of responsibilities once again, do not overload this method with mail sending, user login or stuff like that, the only responsibility of this method is to create an account. To handle the mail sending and other tasks you need to perform after creating an account you can use laravel's `EventDispatcher` class or `Event` facade ([Documentation here](http://laravel.com/docs/events)).
My method would look like this

```
public function createNewAcocunt($firstName, $lastName, $email, $password)
{
    $validation = $this->accountValidator->validate(
            compact('firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'password')
    );

    if($validation->fails())
    {
        $up = new ValidationException('Invalid data for new account');

        // set error messages on exception to communicate them to upper layer
        $up->setErrors($validation->errors);
        throw $up;
    }

    $token = str_random(60)

    // if you use a repository then
    $user = $this->repository->createNewAccount($firstName, $lastName, $email, $password, $token);
    // or do it in whatever way you prefer

    // Now that the user is created fire suitable event
    Event::fire('account.created', [$user]);

    return $user;
}
```

Most of it has already sorted out, now you can catch the event `account.created` and perform whatever action you want.
My advice for sending out emails would be to queue emails instead of sending them in real time, this will decrease the response time since the codes will no longer poll for email to be dispatched

```
Mail::queue('emails.auth.email_confirmation', $data, function ($message) use ($mail_subject)
{
    $message->to(Input::get('email'))->subject($mail_subject);
});
```

[read more about email queue here](http://laravel.com/docs/mail#queueing-mail)

and at last, you can customize the validation error message for **email:unique** rule and make that include a link to login page. check out the [custom error message section over here](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-error-messages). basically you can just pass in an associative array to `Validator` like this:

```
$messages = [
    'email.unique' => 'Looks like you already have an account, please <a href=' . route('login') . '>Log in here</a>'
];

$validation = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);
$validation->errors->get('email'); // should display the message as defined above
```

I hope this will give you at least an idea to get started with. I, for one, am really happy about your decision to go pro.

Comment: Awesome! After I created this thread I've watched the laracasts "SOLID" series (https://laracasts.com/search?q=solid).
I am also reading 'Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftmanship' from UncleBob.
I hope in some time I'll be a real pro. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Just an idea... What if the `create New ACcount($firstName, $lastName, $email, $password)` function accept an array?

Comment: Then it will not be a consistent interface. You can pass in literally just any array with any keys or element, and there is no guarantee that the array you passed in has all necessary elements. It can have extra information, incomplete information or no information at all. By defining atomic argument you can now guarantee the consistency and integrity, now every time this method is called anywhere it must be called with those required params or it will not work